# GPG default values for cypher hash and compression

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am trying to figure out the default values used for cipher, hash and compression when encrypting a file in GPG (GnuPG) version 2.17.2 using following command:

```
gpg -e -r "recipient" --output output.gpg input.zip
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I found the following information that answers this question partially.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86305/what-is-the-default-cipher-algorithm-for-gnupg